# Showing navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in Baidu Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, chinese-locale, baidu

We know that due to [the infamous China GPS offset problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141542/what-causes-gps-offset-in-china), [GPS (WSG-84) map coordinates don't correspond exactly to the coordinate system that state-approved Chinese maps use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444803/does-a-google-maps-coordinate-map-to-the-same-location-in-baidu-maps) (GCJ-02).

The question is, how does one make sure that placing a marker via the Baidu Maps API at the coordinates reported by `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` will match reality?

Would the GPS chip of a device manufactured or approved for use in China return coordinates that don't match the actual position of a user, in order to instead match he GJC-02 maps?

Does it matter if the user runs a Chinese navigator (e.g. Maxthon, or Google Chrome localized in Chinese), vs. a non-Chinese browser, e.g. Firefox in English?

Here's a [JSBin that tests geolocation and uses the Baidu Maps coordinates conversion API](http://jsbin.com/panomu/2/). Unfortunately I'm not located in China so I can't test.

#### Here's the question:

Does the app above need to run the Baidu coordinates conversion on the coordinates it gets from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in order to show the location correctly on the Baidu Map, or not? Could someone located in China test, ideally with both a Chinese browser on a Chinese-manufactured device, and with a non-Chinese browser on a non-Chinese device?

Answer (score 0):

Umm... first of all, it seems like they have a API to do just that: [raw gps location to baidu gps location](http://developer.baidu.com/map/jsdemo.htm#a5_2).
I was not able to find the documentation but I think their `jsfiddle(?)` might give you an idea to get started.

as of the devices, and browser.. Since Xiaomi phones are working fine in the US, so I guess the android system just returns the normal raw GPS location. Also the Chinese browsers, using them in a US phone still gives me the correct position. so I think the browser has nothing to do with the shift too.

hope this help.

Comment: Umm... first of all, that is exactly the API I use in my JSfiddle: "uses the Baidu Maps coordinates conversion API". My question is, do I need to run the raw GPS location to Baidu coordinates conversion when plotting a photo on the map, or not?

Comment: I think so. Based on some photos I took in Macau, the answer seems to me yes. `BaiduAPI(photosGPSInfo)` returns the real location of this photo.